# Visual Studio 2017 Не открывается опция Project -> Add Reference

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Хочу добавить тему.dll в Проект (C#). Посмотрел на ютубе в видеокурсе. Добавление происходит через опцию Add Reference. Но у меня при нажатии выскакивает ошибка:

> The operation could not be completed. Интерфейс не поддерживается

Все перегуглил не нашел ответа.

Comment: скачай нужную ссылку через nuget

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте очистить директорию:

```
%LocalAppData%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

За VS 2017 не ручаюсь, но на VS 2015 помогало.

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/276#issuecomment-166650817

Comment: Пробовал, осталось так же.

Answer (score 0):

По Add Preference так и не разобрался. Но само добавление тем решил через правой кнопкой на Toolbox -> Choose Items... -> Вкладка .Net Framework Components -> Кнопка Browse... Выбираю dll и стильные компоненты добавляются в Toolbox.